# cpanel software not providing "easy apache 3"

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

I have a dedicated vps (centos 6), with whm cpanel.
To match my server i have installed cpanel to my local (cent os 7)

The "easy apache 3" module is missing under the software's category.
i would like to mirror the production environment to the local.
How can I get "easy apache 3" on my local cpanel?

Comment: Are installed DNS only cPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you havent yet installed cpanel, then create the
/etc/install_legacy_ea3_instead_of_ea4 file before you begin the cPanel & WHM installation process.**

but if the cpanel is allready installed
you can try to install easy apache3 module after the installtion of the cpanel and migrate ea4 to ea3.
then follow the steps
1. mkdir /usr/local/apache.ea3/ 
2. /scripts/migrate_ea3_to_ea4 --revert --run 
3. After switching on the ea3 whm menu does not appear. 
solution.
https://ipadress:2087/yourcpsession12345678/cgi/easyapache.pl
then make php compilation process in the whm menu will appear after completion.